# Why does OnShow for main form not fire?

Tags: winforms, delphi, events

I have some stuff in the `OnShow` event of a main form that fills a few listboxes with a procedure `StuffLB`. I need these listboxes refilled after any of my other forms have been shown with a call to `ShowModal`.

After such a modal form closes, the main form is just repainted there where the modal form was and its `OnShow` event does not fire.

The only way I can get the `OnShow` event to fire is by:

```
frmM.Hide;
frmB.ShowModal;
frmM.Show;
```

Is the only way I can get the listboxes filled to use the `StuffLB` call after every `ShowModal` call on sub forms? I have about 25 forms that are available.

I would had hoped that OnShow meant when it was shown again, either in part or in full.

I'd appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: You main form is clearly visible behind the modal form. `OnShow` fires when a form changes from hidden to visible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`OnShow` event fires when form becomes visible. What you may use is `OnActivate` event. However, since it is your code that calls `ShowModal` of another form, just put required code in a separate method and call here and in `FormShow`.

Comment: `OnActivate` doesn't fire after closing the modal form. Putting the relevant part of `FormShow` into a separate method and calling it after the `ShowModal` is a good idea, though.